# Java Applet: fast dragged mouse creates huge gap between dots

Tags: java, applet, awt

My aim is to draw dots when the mouse is dragged.
The problem is that when the mouse is moved very quick the distance between the dots gets huge instead of the small desired distance, that would not be recognized.

The shortened code is:

```
public void update(Graphics g){
    paint(g);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
        for(i = 0; i <= height; i++){
            for(j = 0; j <= width; j++){
                if(virWorld[i][j] == 1) bufferGraphics.fillRect(i,j,1,1);
            }
        }
        g.drawImage(offscreen,0,0,this);
 }

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt){
    curX = evt.getX();
    curY = evt.getY();
    virWorld[curX][curY] = 1;
}


public void run(){
    while(true){
        repaint();
        try{
            Thread.wait(10);    
        }
        catch(Exception exception){
            System.out.println(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help,
Robin

Comment: You might want to ask a question and indicate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The run() method is unnecessary as repaint() will be called from the Event Dispatch Thread when required.

Comment: Don't forget to followup, as in accept an answer or indicate why answers don't suit your needs!

Answer (score 2):

So it does. You need to interpolate between the previous point and the current point ie draw a line between your two points. Also, you may want to set a thicker Stroke when you do this

Comment: thanks alot that was already in my mind, but i thought there might be a basic problem why that actually happens.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a line between the distant points, or try a curve if you are adventurous.

Comment: If you are not at least a little adventurous, I doubt you'd be suited to programming. ;)

Comment: Just curious: How would you draw a curve? By smoothing over 3 or more points?

Comment: See classes like [`Ellipse2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html) , [`CubicCurve2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/CubicCurve2D.html) & [`QuadCurve2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/QuadCurve2D.html) which render smooth curves based on just a few control points.